# Binding Energize.js clicks to Google Analytics PhoneGap Build plugins

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm writing an app using PhoneGap Build, jQuery Mobile and Energize.js (to speed up clicks)

My wish is to bind an 'event' to the Google Analytics plugin for PhoneGap Build, so that I can track user clicks.

As you can see below, my tracking listener is bound to a 'touchstart' event. At the moment, none of the tracking is working. I am unsure if it is because I have bound to an incorrect action (which Energize.js may have changed) or if there is another issue in my code.

Any help would be appreciated. My account on Google Analytics is set as a 'Webpage' instead of 'Mobile App' as per the plugin guidelines.

```
$(document).on("touchstart", ".condition-list-item a", function() {

    var deviceID = device.platform + '.' + device.uuid;
    // Generates unique variable for each device
    var conditionVar = $(this).attr("data-condition");
    // Pulls ConditionName from list item clicked
    PageButtonClicked(conditionVar);
    // Fires 'Page' tracking to Google Analytics, with ConditionName as 'Page'
    VariableButtonClicked(deviceID, conditionVar)

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
    // Creates an object 'Position' using Geolocation API
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var geo = position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude;
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you add an alert() to the top of your event listiner? If nothing happens, you can be sure it is bound improperly.

Comment: Thanks Dom. That's a very simple and helpful piece of troubleshooting advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".condition-list-item a").on("touchstart", function(e){
        //your function
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dom, for the great reply. I haven't had a chance to implement this yet but clearly you've given a wonderful answer and I've therefore  accepted it until I get the chance to confirm it by implementation. I really appreciate your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

As follow-up, the above code is still not working. Google Analytics is currently attempting to track the information as if it were a website (as recommended by the plugin).

I change the settings on the Google Analytics website to track as if it were a Mobile App. I still think the above code is not working; however, Google Analytics' built in tracking takes care of much the same stuff and is working beautifully.